# How to pass two date variables as a concatenated string for destName to copyByName(srcName, destName, index) in LibreOfficeCalc(4.2.8.2)

Tags: libreoffice

thanks in advance. The Title sums it up fairly succinctly, but for illustrative purposes, here is what I'm **trying** to do:

```
Sub Main
dim doc as Object, sheet as Object
doc=ThisComponent
numSheets=doc.Sheets.count()
sheet=doc.Sheets(numSheets-1)
sheetName=sheet.Name
currentDay=Date()
lastDay=sheet.getCellRangeByName("B1").value
mon=Month(lastDay)

Select case mon:
    case 1:
        monMod=31
    case 2:
        monMod=28
    case 3:
        monMod=31
    case 4:
        monMod=30
    case 5:
        monMod=31
    case 6:
        monMod=30
    case 7:
        monMod=31
    case 8:
        monMod=31
    case 9:
        monMod=30
    case 10:
        monMod=31
    case 11:
        monMod=30
    case 12:
        monMod=31
End Select
nextMonEnd=CDate(lastDay+monMod)
If currentDay > lastDay Then
    newName$=CDate(lastDay+1) & "-" & CDate(nextMonEnd)
    doc.Sheets.copyByName(sheetName, newName$, numSheets) '<--
    newSheet=doc.sheets(numSheets)               'this part here is the 
    newPrevious=newSheet.getCellRangeByName("A1")'snag.Throws a Runtime 
    newPrevious.string=CDate(lastDay+1)         'Exception, Message: .
    newEnd=newSheet.getCellRangeByName("B1")    'I think it's passing a 
    newEnd.string=CDate(nextMonEnd)             'null, but I don't know
End If                                          'why. Any help would be  
End Sub                                         'greatly appreciated
```

If I hard-code the destName arg, it runs clean. I've tried several different approaches, but any variable I pass as the destName throws an error. Thanks again, guys and gals.

Amended: With some help(see comments), I came up with this working revision of my macro, all else remaining the same. Posting it for relevance.

```
nextMonEnd=CDate(lastDay+monMod)
newFirst=CDate(lastDay+1)
newName=CStr(Format(newFirst, "mm-dd-yyyy")) & " " & _
CStr(Format(nextMonEnd, "mm-dd-yyyy"))
If currentDay > lastDay Then

    doc.Sheets.copyByName(sheetName, newName, numSheets)
    newSheet=doc.sheets(numSheets)
    newCurrent=newSheet.getCellRangeByName("A1")
    newCurrent.value=lastDay+1
    newEnd=newSheet.getCellRangeByName("B1")
    newEnd.value=nextMonEnd
    print "New Monthly sheet added."
End If
```

Comment: What's the value of the `lastDay` variable?

Comment: "05/06/2016", formatted as a date.

Comment: so, with some testing, i can use variables with integer and string values for copyByName arguments, but either the concatenation or the CDate() function is causing the error. Using test="cat" and test=4, copyByName(sheetName, test, numSheets) works properly.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the resulting sheet name contains prohibited characters. In OpenOffice.Calc,

> you can only use letters, numbers, spaces, and the underline character in the sheet name.

([OO Calc FAQ](https://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/FAQ/Calc/Miscellaneous/How_can_I_rename_a_sheet%3F))

The sheet name you've built contains slashes `/`, yielding an invalid sheet name.

Comment: Hmmm. Well, that doesn't help matters, but it's not exclusively the problem. even using the "Format" function to replace the "/"s with "-"s, it throws the same error.
ex: Format("05/06/2016", "mm-dd-yyyy") 
returns "05-06-2016", so I worked it into my macro, and the new sheet name should be "04-07-2016 05-06-2016". I printed the variables before passing them, they show the right values, but won't pass through copyByName().

Comment: Ok, so with amended code, I used these: 
`nextMonEnd=CStr(Format(CDate(lastDay+monMod), "mm-dd-yyyy"))<br/>
newFirst=CStr(Format(CDate(lastDay+1), "mm-dd-yyyy"))<br/>  
newName=(newFirst & " " & nextMonEnd)<br/>
`

Comment: And it copies the sheet. Took some tinkering, but with your character hint, and some string formatting, managed to get it working. The Macro developed some new behavior I'm unfamiliar with, date comparison doesn't work the way I expected, but the standing question has been resolved, so thanks for that, anyway. :) @tohuwawohu

Comment: Great to hear :-) yes. working with Dates in LO Basic isn't fun...

Comment: Should I amend my question with my updated(working) code? I don't ask many questions on here, so I'm unfamiliar with the procedure.

Comment: I think it's ok to amend the question - alternatively, you may post an additional answer.